# Using ggplot2 to create a line chart showing spread between two variables in each observation

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here's my data:

```
   Assignment first Stage  Grade Type
1        PA06  98.5 final  98.50   PA
2        PA06  98.5 final  98.50   PA
3        PA06  83.0 final  83.00   PA
4        PA06 100.0 final 100.00   PA
5        PA06 100.0 final 100.00   PA
6        PA06  98.5 final  98.50   PA
7        PA06  86.0 final  86.00   PA
8        PA06 100.0 final 100.00   PA
9        PA06  84.5 final  88.00   PA
10       PA06  95.0 final  95.00   PA
11       PA06  83.0 final  90.00   PA
12       PA06   0.0 final   6.75   PA
```

I am thinking that I want a chart with observations along the x axis, showing a vertical line starting at "first" and ending at "Grade".

Notice that often first and Grade will be equal and in that case I get just a dot. Otherwise I get a line with dots at each end. And I want no labels on the x axis.

This may be a little odd, but I am experimenting with my data. I think it should be "easy" but I can't seem to get it.  Here's what I've tried so far:

```
ggplot(x2, aes(x=first, y=Grade)) + geom_line()
ggplot(x2, aes(x=email)) + geom_point(aes(y=Grade, col="blue")) + geom_point(aes(y=first, col="red"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `geom_dumbbell()` from the `ggalt` package:

```
mydf$case <- 1:nrow(mydf)

library(ggplot2)
library(ggalt)

ggplot(mydf, aes(first, case, xend = Grade)) +
   geom_dumbbell(size_x = 2, size_xend = 2) +
   coord_flip() +
   theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
         axis.text.x = element_blank(),
         axis.title.x = element_blank())
```

Data:

```
mydf <- read.table(text="Assignment first Stage  Grade Type
1        PA06  98.5 final  98.50   PA
2        PA06  98.5 final  98.50   PA
3        PA06  83.0 final  83.00   PA
4        PA06 100.0 final 100.00   PA
5        PA06 100.0 final 100.00   PA
6        PA06  98.5 final  98.50   PA
7        PA06  86.0 final  86.00   PA
8        PA06 100.0 final 100.00   PA
9        PA06  84.5 final  88.00   PA
10       PA06  95.0 final  95.00   PA
11       PA06  83.0 final  90.00   PA
12       PA06   0.0 final   6.75   PA", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: I can't seem to install ggalt using Studio. On a Mac I think I see compile errors go by...

Answer (score 1):

```
# Load package
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

# Create example data frame
dt <- fread("Assignment first Stage  Grade Type
PA06  98.5 final  98.50   PA
            PA06  98.5 final  98.50   PA
            PA06  83.0 final  83.00   PA
            PA06 100.0 final 100.00   PA
            PA06 100.0 final 100.00   PA
            PA06  98.5 final  98.50   PA
            PA06  86.0 final  86.00   PA
            PA06 100.0 final 100.00   PA
            PA06  84.5 final  88.00   PA
            PA06  95.0 final  95.00   PA
            PA06  83.0 final  90.00   PA
            PA06   0.0 final   6.75   PA")

# Preprocess the data
dt2 <- dt %>%
  # Add ID
  mutate(ID = 1:n()) %>%
  # Reshape the data
  gather(Class, Score, first, Grade)

# Plot the data
dt2 %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(ID), y = Score)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = Class)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = ID)) +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "")
```

Comment: Nice... But I don't understand how in the gather call, you are using a column name called Class but there is no such column in the preceding data. Could you explain please @yow

Comment: The `gather` function converts a data frame from wide format to long format. Users need to specify a `key` and `value` pair. In this case, `Class` is the name of the new column I am going to create for `dt2`, and `Score` is the name of another new column in `dt2`. The rest of the function call is to specify which columns I am going to use for the key-value conversion. The contents of `Class` are the column name from the columns I specified in `dt`, in this case, `first` and `Grade`. The contents of `Score` are from the contents in `first` and `Grade`.

Comment: Perhaps it is easier to understand by some visual demonstration. Please see this tutorial (https://rpubs.com/bradleyboehmke/data_wrangling) to learn more about `gather` and the `tidyr` package.